# my eclipse crash after use this code (cpu 100% ) , can anyone confirm if the code work or not

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse crashs after using this code (cpu 100% ) , can anyone confirm if the code work or not. I don't know if crash because the code wrong or not

here is the code below

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ClassStudent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int A=0;
        int F=0;
        int total=0;
        int counter=0;
        double Av12;
        int pass=0;
        int fail=0;
        int grade;

        System.out.println("enter grades or enter -1 to exit  :  ");
        grade=input.nextInt();

        while(grade>=0) {

            if (grade>90 && grade<=100) {
                A++;
            pass++;
            }

            if (grade>0 && grade<=59) {
                F++;
            fail++;
            }


            total=total+grade;
            counter++;

        }

        System.out.println("the total is "+total);
        Av12=(double)total/counter;
        System.out.printf("the averge is %.2f %n ",Av12);

        System.out.printf("num of A is %d %n and F is %d%n and fail is %d%n and pass is %d%n ",A,F,fail,pass);

    }

}
```

Comment: As I understand from the loop,  you should change the iteration variable

Comment: Grade always will be greater than 0

Comment: That isn't Eclipse crashing - it is your Java program looping forever because you never change `grade` in the `while` loop. You can still tell Eclipse to terminate the program.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java person, but this should work. I can offer a solution like that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ClassStudent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int A=0;
        int F=0;
        int total=0;
        int counter=0;
        double Av12;
        int pass=0;
        int fail=0;
        int grade;



        do {

    System.out.println("enter grades or enter -1 to exit  :  ");
       grade=input.nextInt();
            if (grade>90 && grade<=100) {
                A++;
            pass++;
            }

            if (grade>0 && grade<=59) {
                F++;
            fail++;
            }


            total=total+grade;
            counter++;

        } while(grade>=0);

        System.out.println("the total is "+total);
        Av12=(double)total/counter;
        System.out.printf("the averge is %.2f %n ",Av12);

        System.out.printf("num of A is %d %n and F is %d%n and fail is %d%n and pass is %d%n ",A,F,fail,pass);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of infinite loop eclipse shows that error. 
I assume you want to check if the input grade is valid entry.
Assuming input grade should be between 0 and 100, 
change `while ( grade >= 0 )` to `if ( grade >= 0 && grade <= 100 )`.